# Displaying joomla articles under given menu

Tags: joomla

Is it possible in joomla to display article under given menu item?

In my case, there is news item in main menu. On main page there are links to articles. I want them to open under news menu instead of main page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you wnat them linked in the actual menu?

Answer (score 0):

By creating a hidden menu item to the article's category (one which simply isn't published in a module), you set that category up as its own page.

Comment: hmm..but I want this menu to be visible under news item. I've done what You said, and links are opening under "hidden menu" item. It's half ok. Is it possible to point those links to news menu item?

Comment: Certainly. I apparently misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the point of the hidden menu if your target is to display them under your news menu item. Just add a menu item for each of your articles under the news menu item. This should fix the problem.